# To show that $a^n \in O(n!)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation, computational-complexity

$\forall n \in \mathbb{N} , a \in \mathbb{R}  \wedge a > 0 $
$$a^n \in O(n!)$$

I need to show it. Probably I should use the Induction but I am not sure, anyone has tips for me please?

Comment: Why are you selecting $n$ beforehand? Isn't $n$ the variable of the function you want to prove has at most factorial growth?

Comment: The series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a^n}{n!}$ converegs (to $e^a$), hence we even have $a^n\in o(n!)$.

Answer (score 0):

Try logarithms:

$\begin{align*}
  \ln a^n
    &= n \ln a \\
  \ln n!
    &=   \sum_{1 \le k \le n} \ln n \\
    &\ge \frac{n}{2} \ln \frac{n}{n} \\
    &=   \frac{n}{2} \ln n + \frac{n \ln 2}{2}
\end{align*}$

The estimate for $\ln n!$ is to take just the second half of the sum, and there the summands are at least $\ln (n / 2)$.